# Craft Element API data output as a hash instead of an array

Tags: php, json, api, serialization

I'm building and API feed using [Element API plugin from Craft](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api), and I'd like the data output to be serialized as a hash, but currently it's returning an array, as example bellow:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

return [
  'endpoints' => [
  'event-name/feed.json' => [
    'elementType' => ElementType::Entry,
    'criteria' => ['section' => 'event1'],
    'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {

  $speakersList = [];
  foreach ($entry->speakersList as $speaker) {

    $speakersList[] = [
      'name' => $speaker->speakerFullName,
      'jobTitle' => $speaker->speakerJobTitle,
      'company' => $speaker->speakerCompany,
    ];
  }

  return [
    'speakers' => $speakersList,
  ];
},
],
];
```

And the output:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "speakers": [
        {
          "name": "John Doe",
          "jobTitle": "Marketing",
          "company": "Company 1",
        },
        ...
```

I've tried the serialize options in the documentation, but none seemed to solve the issue. 
Currently if I'd like to access the `speakers` within `data` I'd have to first access `index[0]` to be able to get to the `speakers` key.

Is there a way to get rid of this array level?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone is it possible to be something like
`data: { speakers: { [....`? So speakers would be a key from data

Comment: As it uses [`use League\Fractal\Serializer\ArraySerializer`](https://fractal.thephpleague.com/serializers/#dataarrayserializer) it nests it like that. `Item` seems to pull out the item, so it would be what you want without `data` nesting, [getResource()](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api/blob/88f591e87ce2fe8579dd34be9120962a243b1146/src/resources/ElementResource.php#L129) looks promising. So try the [`'one' => true,`](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api#one) option.